# What is are the symbolic simplification rules and when do they apply?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I know that the rules `Simplify` are obscure but maybe someone has an idea:

if I evaluate `Simplify[f[g[x]], {Equal[f[g[x]], 3]}]`, I get `3`. I suppose the transformation is Refine because `Refine[f[g[x]], {Equal[f[g[x]], 3]}]` is also `3`.

However, `Refine[f[g[x]], {Equal[f[g[x]], "something"]}]` is `f[g[x]]` because it only applies to numerics. So far so good.

`Simplify[f[g[x]], {Equal[f[g[x]], "something"]}]`, however, evaluates to `"something"` leading me to believe that there is another transformation being applied.

**What is that transformation and when does it apply?**

Here are some cases that confused me further:

- `Simplify[f[g[x]], {Equal[f[g[x]], duh]}]` -> `f[g[x]]`.
- `Simplify[f[g[x]], {Equal[f[g[x]], Minus[3]]}]` -> `-3`, whereas
- `Simplify[f[g[x]], {Equal[f[g[x]], List[3]]}]` -> `f[g[x]]`.

Here is the complexity trace for the last one:

```
Simplify[f[g[x]], {Equal[f[g[x]], List[5]]}, ComplexityFunction -> ((Print@{#, LeafCount@#}; LeafCount@#) &)]
```

->

```
{f[g[x]],3}
{g[x],2}
{x,1}
{x,1}
{g[x],2}
{g[x],2}
{g[x],2}
{f[g[x]],3}
{f[g[x]],3}
{f[g[x]],3}
{f[g[x]],3}
{f[g[x]],3}
```

It seems to not even consider the substituting `List[5]` for `f[g[x]]`.

Comment: I don't think I understand the comment. I know I can define a `ComplexityFunction` that favors certain outcomes (like in this case favoring `f[g[x]]` over `"something"` because it has fewer characters. My specific problem is that, irrespective of the `ComplexityFunction`, `Simplify` never seems to consider the substitution (since it never calls my custom `ComplexityFunction` with the substitution applied). My general problem is that I don't understand how `Simplify` decides which symbolic transformations to apply.